# How to edit a JTable row?

Tags: java, jdbc, jtable, sqlexception

I want a tutorial or a method so that I can highlight a row in a Jtable which grabs its data from a mysql db , then click on edit button so it launches a form that I can use to edit the row and then save. 
I used a method that worked but it threw a lot of exceptions so I think it's a bad design.

Edit : I don't want to use binding yet . I want to write basic code that I can understand.

Edit 2 : Here's what I call to get the key I use in editing query .. I highlight the row and call this function :

```
int id = ((Number) model.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(), 0)).intValue() ;
```

the function body wasn't written by me It's part of `ResultSetTableModel` file

```
 public Object getValueAt( int row, int column )
      throws IllegalStateException
   {
      // ensure database connection is available
      if ( !dbConnection.isConnectedToDatabase() )
         throw new IllegalStateException( "Not Connected to Database" );

      // obtain a value at specified ResultSet row and column

      try
      {


          getResultSet().absolute( row + 1 );
         return getResultSet().getObject( column + 1 );
      } // end try
      catch ( SQLException sqlException )
      {
          System.out.println("Exception from here dude");
         sqlException.printStackTrace();
      } // end catch

      return ""; // if problems, return empty string object
       } // end method getValueAt
```

A resultset closed exception is thrown here and I know the reason is because I used the same resultset before to fill the table . So I want a different alternative.

Answer (score 1):

See [How to Use Tables](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html). But it would be helpful if you could show your code.

---

If your problem is that your application throws a `SQLException` then you need to show your SQL-query and your database schema for that table.

Comment: @Ahmed: But you have to describe what your problem is in more details. Otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: Try moving the ResultSet pointer. Before doing: `getResultSet().absolute( row + 1 );`. Do: `getResultSet.next();`.

Answer (score 0):

> A resultset closed exception is thrown here and I know the reason is because I used the same resultset before to fill the table . So I want a different alternative.

See [Table From Database](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/). The "Table From Database Example" shows how you can create a DefaultTableModel from data in a ResultSet so you don't have to worry about this.